# How to alias multiple LEFT OUTER JOINs

Tags: mysql

I have the following custom SQL that allows sorting custom post types by a taxonomy column. It works, but has an issue when the custom posts are filtered by another taxonomy. Basically, there is a conflict when filtering AND sorting by taxonomy.

**Current code:**

```
$clauses[ 'join' ] .= <<<SQL
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID=object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} USING term_taxonomy_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} USING term_id
SQL;

$clauses[ 'where' ] .= " AND (taxonomy = '" . $orderby . "' AND taxonomy IS NOT NULL)";
$clauses[ 'groupby' ] = "object_id";
$clauses[ 'orderby' ] = "GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY name ASC) " . $order;
```

**Results in db error:**

```
Not unique table/alias: 'wp_term_relationships'
```

This is because wp_term_relationships is already referenced due to the taxonomy filter.

**A fix?**

```
$clauses[ 'join' ] .= <<<SQL
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID=tr.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt USING tr.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} tms USING tt.term_id
SQL;

$clauses[ 'where' ] .= " AND (tt.taxonomy = '" . $orderby . "' AND tt.taxonomy IS NOT NULL)";
$clauses[ 'groupby' ] = "tr.object_id";
$clauses[ 'orderby' ] = "GROUP_CONCAT(tms.name ORDER BY tms.name ASC) " . $order;
```

My attempted fix has problems, but I haven't been able to tell by examples where I've got it wrong. I suspect that not everything needs to be aliased. It just seems that it all needs to be isolated with the exception of `{$wpdb->posts}.ID` in the first JOIN.

The above sets the query's orderby. How can I use aliases for all of the above tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigni an alias

```
$clauses[ 'join' ] .= <<<SQL
   LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships}  as t_rel ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID= t_rel.object_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} USING t_rel.term_taxonomy_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} USING term_id
SQL;
```

let's try with on condition instead of USING    (hope the column name are the rights one )

```
  $clauses[ 'join' ] .= <<<SQL
     LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships}  as t_rel ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID= t_rel.object_id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} as tt ON tt.id =  t_rel.term_taxonomy_id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} as te ON te.id =  tt.term_id
  SQL;
```

Comment: Thanks. I've attempted similar to your example, but even the `USING term_taxonomy_id` needs to be aliased - otherwise it is referencing the 'term_taxonomy_id' of the filter? I need to alias that entire block of code so that it stands alone and references only it's own aliases. I hope I've explained that well enough.

Comment: i have update the answer  using proper alias for table name related to term_taxonomy_id

Comment: Doesn't `object_id` also require `t_rel`? I also get an error on `t_rel.term_taxonomy_id`

Comment: you should use t_rel in each occurrence .. answer  updated .

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but it generates an error also `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 't_rel.term_taxonomy_id ... ` Also, there is a $groupby in the bottom three lines that references object_id. See, I understand clearly what you are saying - it is done with aliasing, but I seriously think I've tried every combination (including your example) and still get a db error.

Comment: seems strange to me that  wp don't let you use alias properly ... and the error come after  USING not after the first use of table alias ... .. could you use a proper on clause .instead of USING .? ... or an explicit sql code  instead of DAO/PDO abstracted function)

Comment: I do ok with more simple queries, but this is over my head right now. I don't know if an `on` clause would work. I edited my question and included something close to what I think needed to be done. I think all of those tables need to be aliased. My example also generates the same error as your example. Btw, this extra SQL allows sorting a CPT list taxonomy custom field by its name instead of id. The code works fine except in situations where there is a taxonomy being filtered. I need to alias the entire 6 lines in my question so there are no duplicates from the filter query.

Comment: @rwkiii  i have update the answer  with ON clause  instead of USING (i never  see USING in mysql so  is a bit strange  to me)  hope the column names are right ..

Comment: I added the additional clauses lines to your answer. Using ON instead of USING allowed me to work it out, though I don't know the difference between the two statements. Anyway, thanks!